# Pinged username disappears in comments

Tags: bug, status-bydesign

Strange little bug. I write in a [comment](https://superuser.com/questions/589732/how-to-detect-if-network-is-dropping-udp-packets#comment753502_589743):

> @mpy: Blah blah blah...

And on submitting the comment, the ping ‘@mpy: ’ disappears leaving just:

> Blah blah blah...

It would also disappear every time I tried to edit it back in. Stubborn.

<s>No idea whether mpy actually got pinged. :-S</s>

Comment: Oh, I guess this is actually intentional. mpy will have been pinged because mpy is the “post owner” of the answer. A little reminder would be polite, rather than just automatically editing my comments for me. I don't like that, at least not without an explanation.

Comment: Relevant MSO: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184797/pop-up-to-explain-that-nameofanotheruser-being-stripped-out-on-purpose-and

Comment: @Oliver: Thank you.

Comment: @JamesHaigh (at)JamesHaigh If you think it's a problem, please vote that question up.  ;)

Comment: @A.M.: Already have. ;-) But hey, how did you manage to start with ‘`@JamesHaigh`’? And why is it followed by ‘`(at)JamesHaigh`’? Strange. :-S

Comment: OK, now *that* was just weird.  It just let me "@" you!  It's like the @-stripper function is trying to talk me out of my crusade against it by playing nice.  I want to document what happened because of how strange it was:  I typed in 3 "@..."s as a joke, expecting that maybe the first one would get stripped out.  I went to submit, but got the pop-up about addressing more than one user (ha), which *also* happens to mention that the post owner will get a notification (oddly appropriate message here).  ...then I deleted 2 of the "@..."s, typed in my fake one, and...the "@" appeared as well!

Comment: Lol! It's quite funny! Anyway, it's now down to the MSO post.

Comment: As soon as a third user joins the conversation, direct @-replies work for all users. If there are only 2 users in the conversation, @-replies are stripped out. Because Oliver had commented, AM was able to @-reply to James because it was no longer inherently obvious if he was replying to James or Oliver.

Comment: @nhinkle Thank you for clearing that up.  I have to admit that I read a comment just *yesterday* where someone explained just that on Meta Stack Overflow, and yet it still didn't come to me here.  I'm going to count that as evidence of it being unintuitive.  ;)

Comment: @A.M. I agree that it's unintuitive, and I wish you could just put `@whoevertheheckyouwant`. Hopefully you at least understand how it works now so you won't be confused in the future!